# "as...as it gets" Vs. "as...as can be"

Tags: meaning

> This village is as peaceful as it gets.
>
> This village is as peaceful as it can be.
>
> This village is as peaceful as any can be.

Why they are all different, especially first and second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As peaceful **as it gets*** is ambiguous: it may mean

1. "as peaceful as any place anywhere (within the frame of reference) ever becomes", or
2. "currently as peaceful as this village ever becomes"—other places may become more peaceful

*As peaceful **as it can be*** has meaning #2.

- Note that this is not the same thing as *As peaceful **as can be***, without the *it*—that has meaning #1.

*As peaceful **as any can be*** has meaning #1.

Note that none of these entails a high degree of peacefulness. That depends on the contextual frame of reference: you may be speaking of a very peaceful village ***or*** of a very agitated village which is less agitated than usual, or of a moderately agitated village in a very agitated universe.

Comment: His third example is "as can be," not "as can get."

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is wrong with any of those. All are grammatical, and they progress in tone from simply declarative to nearly poetic.

The phrase "as ... as it gets" is very common, and is often used as a superlative intensifier. It means that something is the highest degree that can be achieved in whatever is being judged. Sometimes it's used in a negative or ironic way. For example, if you rent a hotel room and find bedbugs you might wonder: "Is this as good as it gets?"

There's even a movie titled "As Good As It Gets" where the main character, Melvin Udall, uses the phrase ironically. He's in a psychiatrist's office and as he passes through a waiting room full of depressed people he says:

> **Melvin:** What if this is as good as it gets?
>   **Woman Patient:** [sigh of despair]

To say that something is "as ... as it can be" is high praise. Normally the phrase is heard without the *it*: "... as peaceful as can be." To add the *it* intensifies it and makes it a tad more eloquent or poetic.

To say that something is "as ... as any can be" makes the leap into eloquence and poetry. This is something that can seem overly pretty and even self-conscious, so be aware of that effect if you merely wish to state a fact.